# Updating Text Area with Status in HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm working to create a HTA application.  I have added a text area in the UI in order to show the status of the process after each an every step.  However, the text area shows only the last status and the intermediate statuses are not showing up.

I understood the issue and tried after every status update line.

```
    document.GetElementByID("status").value="Processing..."
WScript.Sleep 100
document.GetElementByID("status").value="Task Complete..."
```

but no luck.  Please help me how to show all the statuses without skipping.

Comment: Something like: `document.GetElementByID("status").value= document.GetElementByID("status").value & " Task Complete..."`

Comment: Essentially you want to append your new value (probably with a `vbcrlf` line feed in between). Not overwrite the value in the `status` element.

Comment: So what error handling do you have?  From what I understand, Wscript.Sleep does not work in hta files.  Look at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b4958185-da19-428f-aafc-8451a2206cf5 for implementing a sleep function.  On Error Resume Next would show the last status only.....

Comment: Most likely you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code that you didn't tell us about, because `WScript.Sleep` in a HTA *should* raise an error.